# Reverse Picturebox image in c#

Tags: c#, rotation, background-image, picturebox

I want to make a button in my program flip the backgroundimage of the picturebox by 180 degrees so its facing the other way. So please can i have some code for this. I tried using this code:
capturebox.BackgroundImage.RotateFlip = 180;
but this is wrong and the program doesn't compile, please help.

Thanks

***Edit***

Yeah, sorry, i meant a mirror image, basically facing the other way, so for example a picture of a left handed batsmen could then be mirror so it looks like they are a right handed batsmen in cricket. I hope this example helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
capturebox.BackgroundImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
```

Comment: Little hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip.aspx

Answer (score 2):

"Rotate 180 degrees" will set the picture upside down. I guess you want to "mirror" the image?

Anyway, the [RotateFlip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip.aspx) method doesn't take a number of degrees, it takes an value from the [RotateFlipType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rotatefliptype.aspx) enumeration.